# How to store only table with primitive type of Long using Room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, persistent-storage

I have list of Ids ,type of Long which is primaryKey as well,I want to store in DB, If I'm storing like this

```
 @Dao
public interface UserId {
 @Query("SELECT * FROM ids")
Flowable<List<Long>> allIds();


 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
 List<Long> insert(List<Long> Ids);}
```

error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
It means I need to have a class with only one field type of Long? which I should annotate with @Entity

Comment: You cannot "store" a `Flowable`, at least for how I would use the verb "store". Please provide more context around this line of Java code. Where is it? Is it on your `@Dao` class? Does it have an `@Query` annotation?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have updated my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
List<Long> insert(List<Long> Ids);
```

A `Long` is not an entity. You cannot use `@Insert` to insert `Long` objects, in part because there is no table for `Long` values.

You need to either:

- `@Insert` actual entities, or
- Create a `@Query` method, with SQL that explains what you plan on doing with those `Long` values

Also, I suspect that your existing `@Query` will not work, now or in the future, as Room will not know what `Long` you are expecting. It *might* work if you happen to have only one suitable field in whatever entity defines the `userfavoritestore` table. But once you have 2+ integer fields, Room will not know which one you want. Replace `*` in the `@Query` with the actual column name you want to return.